# gem5 x86 kvm doesn't work with error "KVM: Failed to enter virtualized mode (hw reason: 0x80000021)"

Tags: gem5

I tried to run gem5 fs mode with KVM to fast forward linux boot-up and failed with this error.

```
info:   0x4b564d04: 0x0
info:   0x3b: 0x0
info:   0x6e0: 0x0
info:   0x1a0: 0x0
info:   0x17a: 0x0
info:   0x17b: 0x0
info:   0x9e: 0x0
panic: KVM: Failed to enter virtualized mode (hw reason: 0x80000021)
Memory Usage: 33878524 KBytes
Program aborted at tick 186932115
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z15print_backtracev+0x28)[0x15e45d8]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z12abortHandleri+0x46)[0x15f5196]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7fb3c9f7d390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7fb3c8a72428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fb3c8a7402a]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt[0x80f14f]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt[0x18cb151]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN10BaseKvmCPU13handleKvmExitEv+0x1bc)[0x18cb8bc]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN10BaseKvmCPU4tickEv+0x229)[0x18c8d69]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN10EventQueue10serviceOneEv+0xd5)[0x15eb485]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z9doSimLoopP10EventQueue+0x48)[0x160a9c8]
gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt[0x160ad1f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xbd57f)[0x7fb3c93e557f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7fb3c9f736ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fb3c8b4441d]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---
```

I've used the gem5art and slightly modified the runscript not to run spec benchmark and run /bin/bash instead. It seems that this error has happened a while ago and issued in [here](https://gem5-users.gem5.narkive.com/8DBihuUx/running-fs-py-with-x86kvmcpu-failed). It seems that this problem has been fixed by the gem5 v19 but got the same error code. Could anyone explain why this error happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Please create a bug report for it in the bug tracker: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5 Also give you exact gem5 revision, and a gem5 CLI that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the same issue with `./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --cpu-type="X86KvmCPU"`. Have you found the solution?